# Why is -1 raised to an odd power different from -1?

Tags: assumptions, elements

In the following code, shouldn't the result be -1? It doesn't give me anything. Why?

```
Assuming[Element[n, OddQ], (-1)^n]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Assuming[Mod[n, 2] == 0, Simplify[(-1)^n]]` or `Simplify[(-1)^n, Mod[n, 2] == 0]`.

Comment: Namely, two issues: `Assuming` by itself does nothing. It has to be used together with some "transformation"/simplification function (`Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Refine`, `Integrate` ...). And second, you can't say `n` is element of `OddQ`, because `OddQ` is a test function, not a symbol of a set.

Comment: Assuming[Mod[n, 2] == 1, Simplify[(-1)^n]]

Comment: One should not "learn by guessing". You'd have noticed the code `Element[n, OddQ]` simply doesn't make sense if you had checked the document of `Element` and `OddQ`. (Don't miss the **Details** section of the document!) Finally, another possible solution: `Assuming[i ∈ Integers, Simplify[(-1)^(2 i + 1)]]`.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you for the response. However, these are alternative approaches to accomplish the task I want. Why, though, is what I wrote not working?

Comment: @Domen thanks for your answer! (1st) I wouldn't say that `Assuming` does nothing. Check the difference in responses in the following commands: `Integrate[(x^2 - Pi*Abs[x])*Cos[(2 n*x)], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]` and
`Assuming[Element[n, Integers], 
 Integrate[(x^2 - Pi*Abs[x])*Cos[(2 n*x)], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]` (2nd) Indeed, I misused `OddQ`, as you mentioned. Nevertheless, the command `Assuming[OddQ[n], (-1)^n]` still doesn't work.

Comment: @xzczd Indeed, as another user pointed out, I mistakenly considered `OddQ` to be the set of odd integers. This led me to adopt the command `Assuming[OddQ[n], (-1)^n]`, which, however, also does not work.

Comment: 1. As mentioned in the document of `Assuming`, `Assuming` only modifies the variable `$Assumptions`, in other words, if `$Assumptions` are not called, `Assuming` won't have any effect. `Integrate` is a function that owns a `Assumptions` option and the default option value is `$Assumptions`, that's the reason why `Assuming` plays a role in `Assuming[Element[n, Integers],   Integrate[(x^2 - Pi*Abs[x])*Cos[(2 n*x)], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]` 2. `Assuming[OddQ[n],...` doesn't make sense either, because `OddQ[n]` is simply not an assumption, once again, please read the document of `OddQ` carefully.

Comment: @xzczd First of all, thank you for your detailed response! I assumed that the function `Assuming[assum, expr]` evaluates `expr` for values of variables that make `assum` true. This led me to `Assuming[OddQ[n], (-1)^n]`. In any case, I will take a closer look at the document of `OddQ` because that seems to be the source of all troubles.

Comment: Functions which end in `Q` cannot be used to in assumptions, as they evaluate immediately. Think of these as "programming functions" rather than "math functions". Functions that end in `Q` always evaluate immediately to either `True` or `False`. `OddQ[n]` will immediately evaluate to `False` for any input that is not of type `Integer` and not odd. Thus `OddQ[n]` evaluates to `False` because `n` is a symbol, not a number. Here's we're looking at the data type of the object `n` ("programming view"). We're not looking at what mathematical concept it might be used to represent.

Comment: @Szabolcs , I understand! I think all my questions have been clarified now. Thank you all very much!